# Оператор delete в деструкторах

Tags: c++, деструктор

Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понимаю, что этот оператор в деструкторе используется только применительно к атрибутам, являющимися указателями на объекты других классов, в случае же например vector или string, или int[5] (и к переменным примитивного типа) использовать нужный оператор не нужно?

Comment: `delete` используется для удаления всех объеков созданных с помощью оператора `new`

Comment: Начнем с того, что `delete` к **не**указателям применять нельзя - так что в вектору или строке их просто не применишь :)

Comment: Т.е. нет никаких подводных камней, если следовать простому правилу где new там и delete? оператор new ведь выделяет место в куче, а delete соответственно возвращает это место в свободное использование, а что тогда с типом vector, ведь это динамический массив, стало быть он работает в куче и после него вроде бы нужно освобождать место.

Comment: Вектор ведь *сам* выделяет память? Ну вот пусть *сам* и освобождает. Все равно он вас внутрь не пустит...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понимаете, ну ответить на ваш вопрос "да - да, нет - нет, а что сверх того, то от лукавого" - нельзя. Применяйте `delete` к тем указателям, которые должны быть уничтожены. Это не обязательно *указатель на объект другого* **класса** (например, вы можете выделить память для строки в стиле C - это указатель на `char`). Его может быть не нужно применять даже к атрибуту-указателю - например, при работе со счетчиком ссылок.

Словом, тут очень много тонкостей. Но если рассматривать только *тривиальные* случаи - типа выделения памяти в конструкторе и освобождения в деструкторе - то да, вы понимаете правильно...